# In Messaging.SendEmailResult what does the errors attribute contain?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I'm sending multiple emails using `Messaging.sendEmail`. After that I'm checking for the results by looping over the `List<Messaging.SendEmailResult>` just like the example below. Now my question is: what does the **errors** attribute contain? I tried to trigger send email error but it wasn't successful. I need to know if I can use the errors attribute to get the email address of the ones that failed or somehow find out which email from the list of emails failed. Thank you!

```
for (Messaging.SendEmailResult mr : mrs) 
{
    if (!mr.isSuccess()) {
        system.debug(mr.errors);
    }
}
```

I've also checked the following apex class documentation `SendEmailError Class` but didn't find anything that could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`errrors` is a list of `SendEmailError`. You can Iterate and collect errors:

```
for (Messaging.SendEmailResult mr : mrs) 
{
    if (mr.isSuccess()) {
        //Do something for success
    }  else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Messaging.SendEmailError err : mr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

See methods for SendEmailError [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_sendemailerror.htm#apex_classes_email_outbound_sendemailerror).

Comment: What about the attributre `errors` mentioned in `system.debug(mr.errors);`? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: `errors` is a list of SendEmailError, you can access it directly or via using the getter `getErrors()`. It is better to use documented methods because moving forward this attribute can be made private.